# How to fetch cookies or set cookies in axios interceptor in NextJs

Tags: typescript, cookies, next.js, axios, server-side-rendering

I am using nextjs 13 and migrating from Create React App
In the getServerSideProps function as part of SSR (Server Side Rendering), I am trying to use React Query and make a axios call to fetch data, the axios call has a interceptor at request and response

```
await queryClient.prefetchQuery(['Todo', programId], () => AxiosCall({}))
```

At request, it is trying to check for cookies and use them to populate the request.

```
axiosClient.interceptors.request.use(async (request: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
   // Code to access cookies and add them to the request here 
});
```

Considering the context object is only available through the functions under getServerSideProps and these interceptors are independent functions, how do I access context object to get and set the cookies or perform redirects when the axios call fails ?